# Вызов других python скриптов

Tags: python, windows

Нужно, чтобы один скрипт вызывал другой, как это сделать? Скрипты лежат в одной папке.
Нет, в один файл слить нельзя заранее.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А можно поточнее, что именно нужно?  Интеграция кода в `globals()` делается так:

```
execfile("filename", globals()).
```

Вызов из консоли:

```
import subprocess; 
subprocess.Popen("filename", shell=True)
```

Comment: Эмм .. интеграция кода не нужна .. 
Есть скрипт 1.. вся его работа заключается в том чтобы вызвать скрипт 2 , больше ничего ...При этом 1 скрипт сам выключается

Comment: Тогда import subprocess; subprocess.Popen("filename", shell=True)

Answer (score 2):

Делается как и с обычными модулями через import. [Здесь](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/620147-how-execute-python-script-another-python-script) хорошо описано несколько способов.

Comment: Это и есть просто сливание в один файл , тут же нужно выполнить 2 разные программы ...

Comment: по линку, описаны способы и без сливания, через system к примеру.